# POSTFIX: for a given sender allow only a set of recipients from same domain

Tags: postfix-mta

If I have a mail system **sampleMail.com** with 100 users. There are 10 less-privileged users. I want to restrict less-privileged users such that they can send mail only to a group of selected **FIVE mail ids** in **sampleMail.com**, not to any other mail ID.

How to implement it?
Please help.

Comment: SO is not a config writing service.